# C "for" loop issue

Tags: c, for-loop

I am running this program

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
  int n;
  int a = 1;
  int b = 2;
  int product;
  int i;

  printf("How many numbers of the sequence would you like \n");
  scanf("%d",&n);

  for (i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
    printf("%d\n",a);
    product = a * b;
    a = b;
    b = product;
  }

   return 0;
}
```

When I enter n = 3, the result is 1    2     2
Why is it ? I meant to make it so it show 1  2  4  , what have I done wrong ? And why is it print  1  2  2  .

Comment: Use the Debugger, [Luke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Force_(Star_Wars)#Quotes)!

Comment: @UweKeim, who is Luke BTW?

Comment: What is your recursion formula?

Comment: You did it right, just not printing what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I meant to make it so it show 1 2 4

Then interchange the below two lines

```
 a = b;
 b = product;
```

It should be

```
for (i=0;i<n;i++)
 {
 printf("%d\n",a);
 product = a * b;
 b = product;
 a = b;
 }
```

Comment: Your recursion formula is u(n+1) = u(n)² , i think he wants u(n+2) = u(n+1)*u(n)

Comment: I'm sorry but that answer is wrong. The program will show 1 2 4 for n = 3, but also 1 2 4 16 for n = 4.

Comment: @Saiph, that could be possible but how do you know my recursion formula isn't correct. Did OP mentioned anywhere in post about the specific series he is looking for? What you are saying is based on your own speculation.

Comment: He didn't give the formula, but he obviously implemented u(n+2) = u(n+1)*u(n). Also if that was what he wanted, just b = b*b would be enough and all the other variables would be useless.

Answer (score 2):

> And why is it print 1 2 2 .

Step-by-step trace at `printf("%d\n",a);`:

```
i  a  b  product
0  1  2  ?
1  2  2  2
2  2  4  4
3  4  8  8
4  8  32 32
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code does exactly what it's supposed to do.

Maybe you wanted :

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 int main ()
 {
 int n;
 int a = 1;
 int b = 2;
 int product;
 int i;

 printf("How many numbers of the sequence would you like \n");
 scanf("%d",&n);

 printf("%d\n",a);

     for (i=1;i<n;i++)
     {
     product = a * b;
     a = b;
     b = product;
     printf("%d\n",b);
     }    

 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: but don't input 0 please

Answer (score 0):

`1 2 2` because you print `a` not `product` and value of `a` in each iteration is -

```
  1st iteration a=1
  2nd iteration a=2        // a=b and b=2 i.e a=2
  3rd iteration a=2        // why ? because again a=b and b did not change 
  thus output 1 2 2
```

Simple solution would be -

1.Initialize `product` to `1`   `// int product =1;`

2.print `product` instead of `printf("%d\n",a);`  `// printf("%d\n",product);`

Comment: Thank you, your answer was helpful too, I confused myseft , but I got it now.